# Script TFS Powertools shell extension getter

Tags: scripting, tfs-power-tools

Is there a simple way to script the TFS powertools "get latest version" feature ?
I am refering to this window:

[image: screenshot]

I just want to get it via a script, rather than by right clicking on a folder. I am aware of `tf get` but I like the powertools window better

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window you are showing above is not specific to TFS Powertools.  That is the basic get window that comes packaged with TFS.  Based on that fact, I am not 100% sure I understand your question.

Do you mean to say "How can I, using tfpt, do a get latest version and show this window." Maybe you are simply asking how to display the TFS window from the command line or via script?

TFPT has getcs if you know the latest changeset but that doesn't display in a window.  TFPT adds features that TF doesn't have so obviously TFPT will not have a basic get.

I am unaware of a way, via a script (which would rely on tfpt or tf) to get latest in TFS and then display the aforementioned TFS get window.  I can't think of any reason why there would be a need for this either.  There is command line syntax to handle the gets.

Of course there are commands that will display in the viewer because it wouldn't make sense in plain text; however, since the get command simply gets files it wouldn't make sense to pop the viewer.